# Is .sys file enough for driver?

Tags: c#, driver, device-driver, image-scanner

I've got scanner device **driver package** contains 3 files:

1. Scanner.inf
2. Scanner.cat
3. Scanner.sys

I'm not sure this driver package is full.

**Questions:**
1. Are these files enough for driver package and normal device working?
  Or driver package has to contain DLL file as well?
2. How to send command 'Scan page' to scanner device from C# if I've got just these 3 files (*Scanner.inf, Scanner.cat, Scanner.sys*)?

Answer (score 2):

The `inf` file should tell you which files it expects. Yours should have:

```
(...)
[Version]
(...)
CatalogFile=Scanner.cat
(...)

[SourceDisksFiles]
Scanner.sys=1
(additional files you're missing...)
```

See [Overview of INF Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549520(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Which tool are you to advise to view .sys file content (its functions, etc) ? This way I can understand whether .sys file 'includes' some other dll and libraries or no.

Comment: .sys is a compiled binary, intended to run in kernel mode. You probably won't be able to read anything from it, even if you used advanced tools like dis-assemblers or dependency walkers.
However, the .inf does specify everything that the driver package author intended to distribute, and it's a text file, as my answer shows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those files are enough. The INF file is a Setup Information file, CAT files are used for keeping track of data within a collection of media and the SYS file is the driver itself.

About your second question, you could control the scanner using TWAIN.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1376/NET-TWAIN-image-scanner

http://www.twain.org/